# Is it possible to get code_verifier in IdentityModel.OidcClient?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, oidc-client

[IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) sends the request with the code_challenge already generated. I am [testing the flow on postman to get the token after getting the auth code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token) but I need the code_verifier, is it possible to get the code_verifier oidcclient used to generate the code_challenge?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of [@leastprivilege](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/321)
You can call PrepareLogin which returns

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/main/src/OidcClient/AuthorizeState.cs